# How to go from table view controller to a detail controller and go back

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I have a table view controller with cells and on clicking a cell I want to open a view controller for displaying the details. On the detail view controller I want to have a navigation action like a navigation bar with an item to go back to the table view controller. Then the table view controller should display the last shown cell which I choosed and not the first cell. I hope you know what I mean. And I don't want to have a navigation bar on the table view controller that is displayed. So a navigation controller is maybe not the solution for me.

At the moment my code of the table view controller to open the detail view controller looks like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let vcMissionDetail : ViewControllerMissionDetail = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MissionDetail") as ViewControllerMissionDetail;

    self.presentViewController(vcMissionDetail, animated: true, completion: nil)    
}
```

I use the `presentViewController` to load the detail view controller. Is the use of  `prepareForSegue` the better solution?

And the detail view controller looks like this. I use a navigation bar with a bar button item to go back to the table view controller (Action `goToFeed`), but I'm not happy with this solution. Also I want to open the table view controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerMissionDetail: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func goToFeed(sender: AnyObject) {

        //init view controller for feed
        let vcFeed: UIViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerFeed") as UIViewController;

        //vcFeed.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical

        self.presentViewController(vcFeed, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

THX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you can do to go back to table view controller.
If you have used 'push' to go to detail view controller then do this,

```
    @IBAction func goToFeed(sender: AnyObject) {

    navigationController?.popViewController(...)
}
```

If you have used 'modal' to open the detail view controller then use,

```
        @IBAction func goToFeed(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.dismissViewController(...)
}
```